# Dockerfile for QT compilation: can't find ./configure

Tags: qt, docker, build, dockerfile

I'm writing a dockerfile that installs Qt from source:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ARG QT_FILE_LINK=http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.11/5.11.3/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3.zip

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential

RUN wget --progress=bar:force -O qt.zip $QT_FILE_LINK
RUN echo "Unzipping..." && unzip -q qt.zip
RUN rm qt.zip && cd qt-everywhere-src-* && ls && ./configure \
  -confirm-license -opensource \
  -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-compile-examples \
  -no-xcb \
  -prefix "/usr/local/Qt"

ENTRYPOINT "/bin/bash"
```

The problem is that it fails on the `./configure`, even though you can see that the previous command, which is `ls`, shows that there is indeed a `configure` file.

It says

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./configure: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem because you are using the Zip version, it has Windows end of line style which does not work on linux.

In order to verify that you can add this to your Dockerfile right before executing `./configure` which will convert it to Linux end of line style.

> NOTE: using `unzip -a` while extracting qt.zip will not work as i have tested it already

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' ./configure && ./configure
```

It will work but also it will start to raise other errors because of the same reason as you can see below:

```
+ cd qtbase
+ /qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/configure -top-level -confirm-license -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-compile-examples -no-xcb -prefix /usr/local/Qt
./configure: 49: exec: /qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/configure: not found
```

So in order to fix the whole issue you need to download the `tar.gz` version which suitable for Linux environments